# How to use a Mesh from one project in another?

Tags: import, blend-files

I've been confused about this one for quite some time now. If I were to **create a project of a character by itself**, and I **created another project with just scenery**, **how do I put the character into the scenery?** I've tried using import, but it won't let me put the full character into the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Import* is for other file formats, you're looking for *Link* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> or *Append* <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> both are accessible from the file menu.

While *Append* creates an independent copy of your appended objects, *Link* just references them from the original file.

If you char consist of more than a single object, you should group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> them, this makes it easier to *Append* or *Link*.